# Wh1602D-tml-ct + arduino screen brightness is very low

Tags: arduino, screen-brightness

I have lcd connected to arduino. Everything works fine, lcd shows info properly, but it has very low brightness. I've connected VO via potentiometer to 5 v and even if potentiometer has 0 Ohm, screen has low brightness.
I've tried to use 2 schemes:
1) Using I2C: http://www.instructables.com/id/LCD-display-I2C-adapter-for-Arduino-with-PCF8574A/
2) Direct connection: http://robocraft.ru/blog/arduino/503.html (I think google should translate this)

But result is same.
Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience with hd44780 lcd's, i connect v0 directly to ground. Yours should not be different;  maybe you could try to connect it to 5v, just to be sure the pin is not inverted.

If connecting it to ground makes it work, there is a problem in the potentiometer (or in its wiring). Usually they have 3 pins, the two ones on the sides need to be 5v an gnd, the middle one is your v0

Answer (score 0):

I did it! Thanks for assistance, datasheet for this lcd is horrible...
I'found that A and K contacts are on another side of lcd panel.
I've connect A to 5v and K to ground and I got it.
Thanks!